# Android - Is there a way to find the duration of a running process

Tags: android, service, process

I am trying to find the duration for which the process has been running? Is there a way to find it. I couldnt find a variable under processInfo.

This is the code:

private boolean isMyProcessRunning() {
        boolean check=false;

```
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : am.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {



            temp.append(processInfo.processName);
            temp.append(" ");
            temp.append(processInfo.importance);

            temp.append("\n");

            if(temp.equals("com.location.manage")) 
            { 

                //append the time for which the process has been running
        check= true;  }



    }

    return check;
}
```

}

As you can see I have mentioned in a comment that if the process I am searching for is found i.e. com.location.manage I just need to also add the duration for which this process has been running.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Do you want to know duration for your process or processes running on android phone .P.S-Post your code and what have you tried till now

Comment: duration for process running how long already?

Comment: Yes basically I am trying to find the duration of the process running already on the android phone..Thanks, Nitin

Comment: I have added the code to the question